# Old highly upvoted questions that don't follow current SO standards

Tags: discussion, feature-request, old-questions, popularity, old-answers

As SO has matured, the standards for both asking and answering questions has changed.

There are many [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty?rq=1), [very useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python?rq=1), [very basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/join-two-lists-in-python?rq=1), highly upvoted questions/answers that do not show any research effort.

It makes sense that none of these questions have comments/complaints about lack of research effort, because when they were asked, the site (presumably, I wasn't around) had different standards.

The current standards are concisely covered on the help>Tour page, and in the sidebar when asking a question. However, many new programmers, or light/inexperienced users may only come to the site for these questions, see how these questions are posed, and use that as a template for the kind of research they need to do on questions they ask.

I think it would be good if these old, popular, important, but out-of-date-by-current-SO-standards questions had some kind of label saying that this question/answer followed old requirements, with a link to what the present day requirements are for questions/answers.

The best answers on SO give examples to solve problems, and a lot of users learn through example. Therefore, I think it should be more clear which examples NOT to follow, despite the fact that these style questions/answers are being positively reinforced with upvotes.

NOTE 1: Here I am assuming that a new user would ask an UNASKED question, however there would be no background research, analogous to a question a user might have asked here in 2008 or 2009. However, I am not presuming the question is as simple as the aforementioned linked questions <s>(because they're probably aren't any left to ask)</s>.

NOTE 2: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292170/should-very-old-questions-be-updated-to-newer-standards) because this is an old standard that is more easily remedied. My question is about setting an example for new users, and making it obvious when a seemingly good example (like an old popular question that was poorly researched) should not be followed.

What do you all think?

Comment: your note1 isn't exactly accurate, as new languages appear and these questions can still be asked. But I do get the logic of this post, This would help prevent people from linking questions with decent reception who are bad for "nowadays" Stack Overflow.... not sure if it would really STOP the issue, but at least it would give us something to point to when someone links such a question

Comment: That's definitely true, I am certainly biased by what I see because I'm only ever looking at info related to languages older than the site. Do you have a link to an example question that's extremely basic, but new? I am curious to see how it differs from these older questions.

Comment: Not really, I was just pointing that out. I would assume that new languages with such simple questions would result in downvoted questions nowadays, since we expect more research than we used to?

Comment: I disagree with the premise that these questions don't meet our current standard. These kind of questions - as long as they're not duplicates - are still welcome as far as I'm concerned. They don't meet any criteria for closure and, by your own admission, they meet two out of the three criteria for upvoting (they're clear and useful) and only one of the criteria for downvoting (they show no research effort). Besides, it's hard to see how showing research effort would do anything but add pointless noise to them. I would upvote questions like them if they were asked today and not duplicates.

Comment: See also [Should Stack Overflow be awarding As for effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor) in which SE employee Shog rhetorically asks *"Surely the important goal here is the production of well-asked, well-answered questions, right? Not visible self-flagellation..."* I agree with him entirely. Questions like the ones you've linked to are *absolutely fine*; the "research effort" criteria on the voting tooltips has always been a little misguided.

Comment: see, a new question about a new language in the form of "How do i do x with y?" may be a good question, but it *will* get downvoted, simply due to lack of research. If you look at these old questions of the same form, they are also downvoted, it's just that over time the upvotes have outweighed the downvotes due to the sheer number of people who have had the same question.

Comment: @MarkAmery That'd make a good answer to this question IMO.

Answer (score 30):

These questions may not be received well if they were asked today, but they serve a purpose and do not all need to be cleaned up en masse. @Shog9 has discussed this many times, as I'm sure other moderators and CMs have done, but here are a few of them:

> A fair number of older "canonical" questions have been edited for brevity and made *intentionally more broad* such that they can be used as dup-targets. That's usually a good thing, not a reason to close... - [@Shog9 Aug 21 7:24 PM](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=25239033#25239033)

This chat message pretty much sums up the story for many of these questions.

[Shog has also said this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303086/1768232):

> You're referencing two questions that struck a nerve: they asked, in simple language, something that is implicitly asked *daily* by others struggling to get a handle on how modern C++ should be used. They attracted good answers that became immediately useful in explaining these topics to others.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about what you mean by 'cleaned up', but I am in no way suggesting that any of these questions or their answers be edited. I am just suggesting that they receive a special call out that they don't adhere to the current SO guidelines, in order to make sure less experienced users don't get the impression that these are great questions just because they are popular with many upvotes.

Comment: @spacetyper It's possible, I suppose, to give them a tag of the same purpose as [tag:c++-faq], but honestly I'm not sure what problem you're attempting to solve here.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that we make it more clear to new users that a similar question asked present day would be held to different standards. I don't think a tag would make this obvious enough. I was thinking something more along the lines of the type of notice that historical questions get, except saying "this question was asked before research effort was required, all questions now require research effort, for more info see [link]" or something...

Comment: @spacetyper but that's not entirely true. **Research effort is not required!** However, if you do not show research effort, you will likely get downvoted for it. This is where the confusion comes in. These new users see these old on topic no-research questions with a ton of upvotes, but what they don't see is the 3-10 downvotes that the question has attracted.

Answer (score 24):

Old questions that don't meet the current standards may be eligible for a [historical lock:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

> **What is a Historical Lock?**
>
> A historical lock is a mechanism by which moderators can mark posts as
>   historical artifacts. Questions which are historically locked feature
>   the following post notice:
>
> > locked by Moderator♦ Mar 16 at 20:01
> >
> > This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is
> >     not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do
> >     not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This
> >     question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info:
> >     FAQ.
>
> **What is the purpose of a Historical Lock?**
>
> A historical lock preserves older content that was very popular when
>   it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of
>   scope for the site it is posted on. Historically locking a post ends
>   the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or
>   deleted, and is often the final state of a question that has been
>   deleted and undeleted more than once.

---

That said not all old questions should get a historical lock, only the really useful ones are really eligible and [research effort isn't really a reason to close a question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor)

Comment: By the definition of historical lock, I don't think that would be a very good solution. The reason I say this is because historical lock seems to mostly imply the the question is off topic, or is opinion based. I don't think anyone would say that a question of the type I linked should be deleted if it was asked present day. I think it would just get comments that the author should do more research. EDIT: I agree with the statement in your edit that research effort isn't a reason to close a question.

Comment: @spacetyper: Then wouldn't the comment serve as the notice you're looking for?  It looks like the questions you're talking about are clearly on-topic, they're just rather direct canonical questions. There isn't anything wrong with these per se, as long as they're useful to the community.

Comment: Historical locks are mostly for controversial questions, close/reopen wars, that sort of thing. We are talking about questions that are very broad but people have found useful and continue to come to Stack Overflow to see.

Comment: @durron597 Perhaps you're right... In the broader sense of "How can/do we mark Old highly upvoted questions that don't follow current SO standards?" a historical lock seems to fit the bill.  The specific examples listed seem to fall into a category of "Clearly on-topic, but not well researched...", but we don't really need to bother with those to begin with.